# Publishing Workflow

Tags: content-approval

How to create a share point approval workflow using share point designer . Can anyone help me with the steps. After approval admin need to publish and all the user can able to see those .

Answer (score 0):

here is the [main post.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo) After creating workflow you will click on Publish in the left side of Ribbon, you can also set for workflow if it will run for created or edited items or manually.

[Here is great manual for Approval Workflow.](https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Hope it helps.